# Basic working principle of transformer

Tags: transformer

In a transformer power is conserved and p=vi. So, in a step up transformer, **if secondary voltage is increased the secondary current has to decrease**. Now, my question is, if the secondary winding in connected to a constant load, v=ir rule implies, **if secondary voltage is increased the secondary current has to increase.** These two sentences contradict each other.

Comment: There's plenty of other ways for the circuit to shed unused voltage or current. But probably none you'd actually *like*.

Comment: Almost same: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/230059/if-a-step-up-transformer-increases-voltage-then-how-current-can-be-decreased , and,  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/230404/how-does-the-secondary-coil-of-a-transformer-affect-the-primary-coil-how-is-it

Comment: According to v=d/t, that means that if I go to the store quicker, the store moves closer to me! But according to the real world, the store doesn't move. These two sentences contradict each other.

Answer (score 3):

To make it easier to understand lets make a couple of simplifications:

- we have an ideal transformer
- That transformer has no limits of power transfer.

This ideal transformer will transfer energy form the primary to the secondary with fixed ratio of voltage in to voltage out.  Really it's the ratio of the windings, but lets just assume for now that the voltage is an easy 1:N for every 1 volts in you get N volts out.

You place your resistor across the output and it dissipates power.  You know the voltage, therefore you can measure/calculate the current on the secondary and get the power dissipated.  Because the voltage of the primary is less and the power transferred (remember it is idea) is exactly 1:N then the current will increase by NX on the primary.

If you change the load resistance the current(s) will change.

If you remove the load, the secondary current drops to zero.  0 X N = 0 and therefore no current flows in the primary.

The right way to look at it is that the primary current flow will "see" the secondary's load at a scaling factor of \$N^2\$.  The current changes appropriately.

Now for the real part:  real transformers have limits on the amount of power that they can transfer.  This is the "watt rating" so pulling 10 watts through a 40 W transformer, you can use those simplifying assumptions and call it ideal.  AS you get closer to the 40 W limit then non-idealities come into it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the transformer don't generate energy, it only transfer **energy** from one side to another side, that is why it's called transform**ER**. Omit the various loss in the transfer, the power on the two side always equal.

Assume your secondary connects to a "constant load", such a fixed resistor. And you **make** the the voltage on the resistor rise, so the current flows in the resistor should rise, too. Yes, if the voltage on the resistor rise, the current must rise. But think again, **how and why** can the voltage on the secondary rise? How do you make them both rise without improve the power input on the primary side?

That just is the "[Conservation of energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy)". If the power on the primary side is **fixed**, then if the secondary voltage increase, and the secondary current must decrease. If your primary side can supply more energy, then the voltage and current on the secondary side can both increase.

The working principle of transformer is electromagnetic induction. For more, go here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer.

Comment: Say, the input power is 16 units. Say, the primary voltage is 4v and primary current is 4 amp. For, some turns ratio, secondary voltage is 8v and secondary current is 2amp. Now, if I attach a 2ohm load on the secondary winding then the voltage drop will be 4v. Where the other 4v will go?

Comment: You are confused by what is reason and what is the result. Why you think the current will fixed at "2A"? If your primary side can only support a fixed \$P = 4V \times 4A = 16W\$, then when you attach a 2 ohm resistor on the secondary, the current should be \$(P / 2)^{0.5} = 8^{0.5} \$

Answer (score 0):

For an ideal transformer with no losses, power in = power out. If the transformer is a 2:1 step up transformer then secondary voltage is **always** twice primary voltage.

So, assume you are feeding 16 watts in (4v and 4 amps). This means your output voltage is 8 volts and your output current is 2 amps and this, in turn, implies a secondary load resistance of 4 ohms.

If you attach a 20 ohm load to the secondary and you are still forcing 16 watts into your primary then the 20 ohm load will be dissipating 16 watts and this means it has a secondary terminal voltage of 17.89 volts and a current of 1.118 amps. To achieve this (given the turns ratio is fixed), the input power comprises 8.95 volts at 1.789 amps.